# Variance of stratified random sampling

Tags: statistics, sampling

I am begginer in sampling, so I need help with this exercise.

I am given population of size $N$. For every item $k$ in population we given two data $(Y_k, X_k), Y_k \in \{a,b,c,d\}, X_k \in \mathbb{R}$. We divide population in four stratums (based on $Y_k$ of each item). Stratums have sizes $N_1,N_2,N_3,N_4$.

We do stratified random sampling (sample size $n_i$ for stratum i), and have to calculate sample mean and population variance of each stratum and between stratums.

Procedure for sample mean:

- We calculate the proportions of stratums: $w_i = N_i/N$
- Do simple random sampling for each stratum and calculate stratum sample mean  $\bar{X_i}$.
- Sample mean is: $\bar{X} = \sum w_i \bar{X_i}$.

Equation for population variance inside stratum 1 (symetrical for others): 
$\frac{N_1-n_1}{(N_1-1)n_1} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{N_1} (X_k - \bar{X_1})^2}{N_1}$.

I am lost on how to do population variance between stratums. What does that even mean? Are other equations right? Thank you.

Comment: The variance estimate is based on knowing all $X_k$ in the stratum, not just the sample.

Comment: @herb Yes, that is why I take all of elements in the stratum in the sum. Is this not correct?

Comment: Are you trying to get an estimate of the variance from the sample or from the total population?  You are using the sample mean in the formula, but you are using the entire population to get the variance.  Why not use the population mean, rather than the sample mean?  You should use only sample data or only population data, not mix.

Comment: I am trying to get an estimate of the variance for the total population in stratum 1. Oh so the  $\bar{X_1} $ in variance should be recalculated for whole stratum 1. Thank you! Any idea what it means to calculate variance between stratums?

Comment: You can get mean and variance for the entire population.  I am not sure what you mean by variance between stratum.  My guess would be to use the four population means as the data and compute the variance using these four numbers, but I am not sure what you have in mind.